# How would I de-allocate this?

Tags: c++, memory

Just curious as to how I would delete this once it is done being used.

```
TicTacNode *t[nodenum];
for (int i = 0; i < nodenum; ++i)
{
  t[i] = new TicTacNode();
}
```

Would any pointers that are assigned with values in t need to be deleted as well?? For example,

```
TicTacNode * m = (t[i + 1]);
```

Comment: Remember, each `new` has to have exactly one matching `delete`. So you need a loop that does `delete t[i];`.

Comment: You'd do it in reverse order.  But I wouldn't do that at all.  I don't think I've needed a `new` or `delete` in C++ in the last 8 years.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
TicTacNode *t[nodenum] = {};

for (int i = 0; i < nodenum; ++i)
{
  t[i] = new TicTacNode();
}

...

for (int i = 0; i < nodenum; ++i)
{
  delete t[i];
}
```

Though, you really should use smart pointers instead, then you don't need to worry about calling `delete` manually at all:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<TicTacNode> t[nodenum];

for (int i = 0; i < nodenum; ++i)
{
  t[i].reset(new TicTacNode);

  // or, in C++14 and later:
  // t[i] = std::make_unique<TicTacNode>();
}
```

Or, you could simply not use dynamic allocation at all:

```
TicTacNode t[nodenum];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would any pointers that are assigned with values in `t` need to be deleted as well?

No. However, you have to make sure that you don't use those pointers any more after the memory have been deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

> Just curious as to how I would delete this once it is done being used.

As simple as this:

```
std::unique_ptr<TicTacNode> t[nodenum];
for (int i = 0; i < nodenum; ++i)
{
  t[i] = std::make_unique<TicTacNode>();
}
// as soon as scope for t ends all data will be cleaned properly
```

or even simpler as looks like there is no reason to allocate them dynamically:

```
TicTacNode t[nodenum]; // default ctor is called for each object and all will be deleted when t destroyed
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual you don't have to explicitly allocate and deallocate memory. All you need is the right data structure for the job.

In your case either std::vector or std::list might do the job very well

Using std::vector the whole code might be replaced by

```
auto t = std::vector<TicTacNode>(nodenum)
```

or using std::list

```
auto t = std::list<TicTacNode>(nodenum)
```

**Benefits**:

- Less and clear code.

  No need for std::new, since both containers will allocate and
  initialise nodenum of objects.

  No need for std::delete, since containers will free memory
  automatically when they go out of scope.